# Beginner-Cant import pandas data reader keeps coming up with error can anyone tell me why it is doing this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

`import pandas as pd` works.

But when I put:

`import pandas_datareader.data as web` it comes up with

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-27-bc32bb8bec34> in <module>
    ----> 1 import pandas_datareader.data as web

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader
```

Can someone give some advice because I am just learning for the first time. :)

Comment: I don't use pandas, but by the error it seems like you haven't installed `pandas_datareader`

Comment: `pandas` and `pandas-datareader` are two different packages. You can try to install `pandas-datareader` using `pip install pandas-datareader`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.This helped I had to open my terminal, and pip  install pandas.datareader.This seemed to fix the issue.